# Where do I get a package for GNU Parallel?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) in Ubuntu but I can't find a package for it in the default Ubuntu repos. Where can I get it?

Comment: For posterity: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=597050

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In 13.04, you can install with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install parallel
sudo rm /etc/parallel/config
```

The second line is necessary because GNU parallel is installed in `--tollef` mode (if anyone can provide a rationale for this, I'd like to know).

In 14.04, the config file is apparently no longer included, since the `--tollef` option was removed from the GNU parallel source entirely: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/parallel/2013-02/msg00018.html

Comment: turn this into a wiki answer and let's pile up all the ways to install it (for 10.04, 10.10, 11.X, 13.04, etc)

Comment: Probably available via this method as of Ubuntu 12.10 "Quantal": http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/parallel

Comment: The rationale behind the setting in ` /etc/parallel/config` is perhaps that `moreutils` already include a version of Tollef's `parallel`. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/using-parallel-on-ubuntu.

Comment: All I needed for 20.04 was `sudo apt install parallel` and it just worked. No need for the 2nd line.

Comment: Getting `E: Unable to locate package parallel` error message with *Ubuntu 20.04 LTS*.

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install parallel` works great on Ubuntu 22.04!

Answer (score 13):

https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries?package=parallel&project=home%3Atange&repository=xUbuntu_10.10

This should work well with 10.10.
If not, you could also try the Debian 5.0 Package from [here](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=parallel&project=home%3Atange).

**Edit:**

Just to clarify:
Even though this link is to the OpenSUSE build service, **it is an Ubuntu package**.

Packages for more recent Ubuntu versions are [also available](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=parallel&project=home%3Atange).

Comment: Works fine on my 10.10 x86_64. I was going to build a one-off deb for this, thanks for finding one first!

Comment: Is this package in any debian repos that I can add to be list of sources?

Comment: Debian Squeeze-backport (http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/parallel), Wheezy (http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/parallel), and Sid (http://packages.debian.org/sid/parallel).

Answer (score 8):

As of today (11th March 2015) I recommend reading:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=597050

Basically `moreutils` and `gnu parallel` can't get along.

You can do

```
sudo apt-get install parallel
```

but you will lose `moreutils` - even if you don't use `moreutils` `parallel`, you would lose for example `ifne` as well.

You could build from scratch as in the other answer.

I did

```
sudo apt-get install parallel
sudo mv /usr/bin/parallel /usr/bin/gnu_parallel
sudo apt-get install moreutils
```

And then used `gnu_parallel` in my scripts

Comment: This bug has been fixed in 17.04, finally.

Comment: this might come up on 20.x too. 

If I run parallel on a clean ubuntu image it will claim it's not installed and suggest installing moreutils to get it, but it won't work as expected!

time sink!

Answer (score 7):

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, and there still isn't a Canonical package of GNU Parallel. It's pretty easy to manually add though.

1. Go to the official GNU Parallel site: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/
2. Download the latest source tarball: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/
3. Unpack and make it.

.

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/parallel-20120522.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf parallel*
cd parallel*
less README
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: According to the `README`, the shell code `wget -O - pi.dk/3 | sh` will install this package. If you like piping random webpages to `sh`.

Comment: @shabbychef i strongly discourage that method, but it *is* in the readme.. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

Answer (score 5):

You can use the zeroinstall feed (it should work on any os / distro):

```
apt-get install zeroinstall-injector
0alias parallel http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/packager/0install/parallel.xml
```

then just run it using the `parallel` command.

See http://0install.net for more info about zero install.

Answer (score 3):

I looked today (2011-01-25) and didn't find any ppa or other apt repository. I did find https://launchpad.net/parallel but it only links to external resources.

Also the parallel command in the moreutils package is NOT GNU parallel but http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/ which is not as full featured.

It's in macports and many other distributions so it should be included in Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 2):

It's available in *buntu 13.10 and will be 14.04LTS.

Answer (score 1):

https://launchpad.net/~ieltonf/+archive/ppa/+packages

Or include this in your source.list:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ieltonf/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ieltonf/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it isn't packaged in Ubuntu & Debian, maybe you can request it be packaged.

There are also some other tools with similar features (parallel remote execution of commands on multiple systems) in the repositories that you might want to check out.  (Maybe somebody else can recommend some of these.)

Comment: I requested it be packaged in http://pad.lv/740630

Comment: JanC, the nice thing about gnu parallel is that it's happy to run the commands locally, rather than assuming parallelism is across different machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can install latest version using [LinuxBrew](http://brew.sh/linuxbrew/):

```
brew install parallel
```

As of today, current Version installed is `20150922`.
You can check it's [Formula](http://braumeister.org/formula/parallel).

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 12.04 you can download it from http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-backports/all/parallel/download

and of course install with *dpkg -i*