# Installing GNU parallel utility on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnu

I am trying to install GNU parallel utility on my local ubuntu 14.04.
I downloaded the tar file from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/.

The version is `parallel-20140622.tar.bz2`.

This got downloaded into my Downloads folder and then I opened a terminal and then changed my directory to Downloads and then used

```bsh
tar -xjf parallel-20140622.tar.bz2 ; cd parallel-20140622; ./configure ; make;make install
```

But it gives me this error:

```
varun@varun-OptiPlex-760:~/Downloads/parallel-20140622$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/varun/Downloads/parallel-20140622'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/varun/Downloads/parallel-20140622/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/varun/Downloads/parallel-20140622/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/varun/Downloads/parallel-20140622'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/varun/Downloads/parallel-20140622'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/varun/Downloads/parallel-20140622'
varun@varun-OptiPlex-760:~/Downloads/parallel-20140622$ make install
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/varun/Downloads/parallel-20140622/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/varun/Downloads/parallel-20140622/src'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
 /usr/bin/install -c parallel sem sql niceload '/usr/local/bin'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/parallel’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/sem’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/sql’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/niceload’: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-binSCRIPTS] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/varun/Downloads/parallel-20140622/src'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/varun/Downloads/parallel-20140622/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo` permissions are required for the `make install` step. So try:
`./configure && make && sudo make install`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Pilot6 Did you try?

Answer (score 20):

You should be able to install it using apt-get. Per "[Where do I get a package for GNU Parallel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12764/where-do-i-get-a-package-for-gnu-parallel)":

```
sudo apt-get install parallel
```

In your specific case, though, you'll want to run `sudo make install` instead of just `make install`. Alternatively, you'll need to specify a new root directory to your configure script.

Comment: Thanks steve that would work; can you tell if I am installing the way I posted the question what should I do?

Comment: Sure! Updated the answer.

Comment: parallel doesn't seem to be available in 17.04